Navmesh pro objects can't go through 1x1 spaces
In Unity 2D, I am using NavMesh Pro to add pathfinding to my enemies, but now matter how much I experimented with the inspector I couldn't get the enemies to go through 2 blocks that are 1 tile apart. The NavMesh draws itself correctly, but my enemy would just stop and search for alternative paths instead of going through 2 blocks. My system only works when blocks are at least 2 tiles apart.
My enemy stays there even though there is a possible path between those 2 tables

Here is the NavMesh agent component in the enemy

Here is the Navmesh obstacle component in the table

This is my NavMesh object

I tried changing the radius of the object, and switching to the navmesh modifier component with not walkable enabled, but that didn't work either so I'm currently using the NavMesh obstacle component, which is more effective since my blocks spawn at random positions and this component adjusts them to the NavMesh.

Reduce the Radius settings for obstacles avoidance on your agent .. it requires "at least" 1, the rest is just inaccuracies.
so rather make the radius e.g. 0.8 or something similar
